# how to upload image using tinymce editor

Tags: json, laravel, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor in my Laravel application and i want to use the image upload plugin for which i make a post request to a post controller but when i call the url i got error of **methodnotallowed exception**

here is my code for editor  :

```
tinymce.init({                              
 selector: '#description',
convert_urls: false,
statusbar: false,  

plugins: 'image code print preview fullpage  searchreplace autolink directionality  visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link    table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking  toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount   imagetools    contextmenu colorpicker textpattern media ',
    toolbar: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat |undo redo | image code| link fontsizeselect  | ',

    images_upload_url: '{{url("/admin/upload")}}',

    // override default upload handler to simulate successful upload
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        var xhr, formData;

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.open('POST', '{{url("/admin/upload")}}');
      if(xhr.status = 400){  err= "Invalid file name or Extension";}else if(xhr.status = 500){  err="Server Error";}else if(xhr.status = 403){  err="Origin Denied";}
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var json;

            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status +' '+err);
                return;
            }

            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }

            success(json.location);
        };

        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

        xhr.send(formData);
    },
});
```

and this is the controller am using :

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
Route::post('/upload', 'tinyupload@store');
});
```

and my controller logic is :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{


// Allowed origins to upload images
$accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://107.161.82.130", "http://abhidemo.com");

// Images upload path
$imageFolder = "uploads/";

reset($_FILES);
$temp = $_FILES['file']['name'];
if(is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){
        // Same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
        if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)){
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        }else{
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
            return;
        }
    }

    // Sanitize input
    if(preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])){
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if(!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))){
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    $imagefull=$serverimg.$filetowrite;
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $imagefull));
} else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
}


}
```

the issue am facing is when i try to upload image through my editor to server it is showing wrong type file in error as per my code and method not allowed exception even am using same method POST in both side

Comment: what is exactly the error if you mind?

Comment: method not allowed exception http 500 internal server error

Comment: and why `'{{url("/admin/upload")}}'` instead of `'/admin/upload'` in the xhr request?

Comment: because when i try in that way its not working i mean not calling the route method i define in controller so i use it in laravel way

Comment: no this will result an invalid path, also, try to use postman and make a post request to that path and in the controller dump the request content and see if you are getting it right

Comment: to get the current url in js try this: `window.location.origin + '/admin/upload`

Comment: as per you instructed sir i face issue with route again its showing 404 now its is not getting   " /public/" part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170265/discussion-between-hussein-and-jagdish-sharma).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this code in js :

```
<script>
     tinymce.init({                              
 selector: '#description',
convert_urls: false,
statusbar: false,  

plugins: 'image code print preview fullpage  searchreplace autolink directionality  visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link    table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking  toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount   imagetools    contextmenu colorpicker textpattern media ',
    toolbar: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat |undo redo | image code| link fontsizeselect  | ',

    image_title: true,
            automatic_uploads: true,
            images_upload_url: '{{url("/admin/upload")}}',
            file_picker_types: 'image',
            file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {

                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

                input.onchange = function() {
                    var file = this.files[0];

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    reader.onload = function () {
                        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                        var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                        var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                        blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                    };
                };
                input.click();
            }
        });
                               </script><meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

and this in controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{ 

$file=$request->file('file');
$path= url('/uploads/').'/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
$imgpath=$file->move(public_path('/uploads/'),$file->getClientOriginalName());
$fileNameToStore= $path;


return json_encode(['location' => $fileNameToStore]); 

}
```

Comment: How to get temerory path of image in controller